# Can I make a Windows 10 recovery drive by running a program from a Live USB?

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, clonezilla, liveusb

My computer will blue screen soon after logging in, so I can't make a recovery drive from within Windows. I tried making an image of my recovery partition with Clonezilla, but I didn't understand what to do with the output image (it wasn't in .iso as I expected.)

To clarify: my objective is not necessarily to fix the blue screening but rather to make a recovery drive without booting into Windows (using a live OS). I need a recovery drive because I want to install Linux Mint alongside Windows. l don't  have experience with editing partitions and want to make a recovery drive in case something goes wrong and I lose Windows. I could install Windows 10 fresh with their installation media creation tool, but I would have to install all of my drivers from scratch, and from what I read a recovery drive would keep the drivers. I also want a recovery drive so I can remove GRUB and put the Windows booter back in case I decide to remove Linux Mint.

Comment: Have you tried using Safe Mode.  A recovery drive won't really solve your current problem

Comment: I am not interested in fixing Windows as such. I got Linux Mint to work with a live USB and want to install it alongside Windows. However, I don't have experience with editing partitions and want to make a recovery drive in case something goes wrong and I lose Windows. I could install Windows 10 fresh with their installation media creation tool, but I would have to install all of my drivers from scratch. I also want a recovery drive so I can remove GRUB and put the Windows booter back in place of I decide to remove Linux Mint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author doesn't appear to actually want to solve their problem per their own commentary

Comment: I want to make a recovery drive. My intention is not primarily to fix the blue screen issue in Windows, but to make the laptop usable by installing Linux Mint. The blue screen issue is simply the reason I can't make a recovery drive with Windows. I listed the reason I want to make a recovery drive in my comment: in case Windows is damaged during the installation.

Comment: Download Windows 10 ISO, boot to it, all the recovery tools exist in that environment a recover disk isn't really appropriate to fix the rebooting problem you have (determining the reason it's rebooting would help determine if a recovery disk would even help though)

Comment: Thanks. If I need to reinstall Windows with the new ISO, will Device Manager tell me all of the drivers I need to install?

Comment: Windows Update will just install them.  Unless a specific device is missing functiality then the default driver is fine.  Outside of display drivers which should be downloaded from Nvidia or AMD directly of course.